# Return the latest entries with the same column value

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, vb.net-2010, visual-studio-2015

Good day! I'm stumped on this one. I need to get the latest entries with a given column value, without previously knowing how many entries are supposed to be returned, on an MSAccess DB.

This is a sample of the table I'm working with:

```
ID   OrderNo   Time      Closed
10   14        17:20:05  TRUE
11   14        17:20:09  TRUE
12   15        17:22:53  TRUE
13   15        17:22:56  TRUE
14   14        17:26:26  TRUE
15   14        17:26:30  TRUE
16   14        17:26:37  TRUE
```

In this example, I'd need a query to return *only* the rows 14, 15, and 16. But it could be 3 rows, or 7 rows that would have to be returned. I've tried selecting the entries with the same OrderNo with MAX(Time), but since the milliseconds are different, it only returns the latest entry. Is there a way to get the latest entries with the same "OrderNo" up until "OrderNo" changes?

Sorry if I didn't explain myself well enough, english's not my first language, and I appreciate any help!

EDIT: Here's what I've tried:

```
SELECT        ID, OrderNo, Time, Closed
FROM            Sales
WHERE        (OrderNo = ?) AND (Closed = TRUE) AND (Time =
                             (SELECT        MAX(Time) AS Expr1
                               FROM            Sales))
```

Comment: Please show what have you tried.

Comment: Simply order by Time DESCending and then take you TOP records.

Comment: Thing is I have no way of knowing how many records I need to return. I need to return all of the records with the same OrderNo as the latest entry up until a row with a different OrderNo.

Comment: Not sure you can do this using only an SQL query.

Comment: Hmm.. I thought of two alternatives. I can either add another boolean column which's toggled when a new group of rows with a specified OrderNo value is added, and then the query would have only to return the rows with the second boolean column toggled; or

populate a table with a loop that reads each row and gets them up until it finds another value to OrderNo. Which one would you suggest?

Comment: It all depends on what your logic is. I don't know the purpose and logic behind these records and why you have this requirement. If this requirement is mandatory for your logic then adding another column that helps to isolate the correct records is a good idea, (For example if the inserts for OrderNo 14 are in two distinct sets you can apply an unique number to each set so you can retrieve the set of OrderNo with the highest unique number)

Comment: It's a storefront software. The customer presents a card with a barcode, and the system returns all the products and services the customer has acquired/performed while in the store. But if the cashier makes a mistake, he needs to review the last order on the card. I think I'll go with adding another boolean. Thanks, Steve!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this works:

select ID, OrderNo, Time, Closed from Sales Where ID <= (select max(ID) from Sales where OrderNo = 14) And ID > (select max(ID) from Sales where OrderNo <> 14 and ID < (select max(ID) from Sales where OrderNo = 14))